# How to overwrite Array toString method

Tags: java, arrays, tostring

I want to print the array when `arr.toString()` is called. How can i do that?

```
 Integer[] arr = new Integer[10];

 for(int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
     arr[i] = (i);
 }

 System.out.println(arr.toString() + " " + arr.length);
```

Comment: You can not do that.

Comment: You could just write a method yourself.

Comment: You can't.  There is no possible way.  Deal with it.

Comment: Thanks for the info